# Random text inside css shape

Tags: html, css

I need to put some text inside the css shape.  I have already done up the shape. Now my problem is, how do I make the height of the shape go according to the text contents height? Right now the content is longer than the shape.

Here is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/uE6x4/

```
<div class="trapezoid">
    A hella lot of lorem ipsum text goes here to test the freakin' trapezoid!
</div>

.trapezoid {
   height: 0; 
   width: 80px;
   border-bottom: 80px solid blue;
   border-left: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set initially height of the DIV to 0, this way you can determine client height of the div and assign to border width. And *then* set the height to 0:

```
.trapezoid {
   width: 80px;
   border-bottom: 80px solid blue;
   border-left: 40px solid transparent;
}

document.getElementById('xMyDiv').style.borderBottomWidth = document.getElementById('xMyDiv').clientHeight + 'px';
document.getElementById('xMyDiv').style.height = '0px';
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uE6x4/4/